# Is there an integrated terminal option in file managers such as Nautilus in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, visual-studio-code

Is there a way I have an integrated terminal within a file manager in Ubuntu (like the way terminal opens up with VSCode) so that when I trigger this inbuilt terminal from any folder, it shows the prompt in the same window.

For example: VSCode integrated terminal looks like this:

[image: VSCode integrated terminal]

Now this is achieved by right-clicking and selecting the 'open in Terminal' option, which opens a new window.

Comment: It depends on how 'integrated' it needs to be. In Nautilus you can click right on a folder, or click right on the "empty space" between files, and choose "Open in Terminal". The terminal that opens will be in a separate window, though.

Comment: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/tree/master/nemo-terminal  nemo terminal. and https://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/ nautilus terminal

Comment: Technically, nautilus is not "integrated". It is essentially a third party app that comes pre installed on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the standard behavior of [dolphin](https://kde.org/applications/system/org.kde.dolphin), the stock KDE file manager (which is by itself a sufficient reason to use KDE). However, to use dolphin under Gnome, I think you will also need to install Konsole and it feels a little out of place on Gnome.

An alternative seems to be [Nautilusterminal 3](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/get-terminal-embedded-in-nautilus-file.html). Though, I have not tested this myself, as I am a KDE user. You can install it by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flozz/nautilus-terminal
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nautilus-terminal
```

Since, as of writing this, no Ubuntu 19.10 version is included in the ppa, you can use pip:

```
sudo apt install python-pip python-nautilus python-psutil
python2 -m pip install --user nautilus_terminal
```

The project is hosted [here](https://github.com/flozz/nautilus-terminal).
A deb package can be found [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/flozz/nautilus-terminal/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus-terminal/).

Answer (score 1):

File manager [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn) has options to open a shell or just the command prompt in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

In Thunar you can click *File* → *Open Terminal Here* or the same by *right-clicking* any empty space in a folder.

Answer (score -1):

You should see an option to to open a terminal in the Nautilus menu. If not, use 'synaptic' and enter 'nautilus' into the synaptic search bar. Scan the list for the plugins you wish to install.

Comment: Synaptic didn't find that option. Maybe that package was added by a PPA.

Comment: the latest synaptic should show a menu box item when you right click an open space in the directory.  have you the latest revision?

Comment: I have the same version of Synaptic in 18.04 as the default version to be released  in 20.04, which I assume to be the latest version, but there is still no package to open a terminal in the Nautilus menu in the list of the plugins to install.